# Special Characters inside a string in REGEX

Tags: regex

Hi have a following string:

Phil-Asia Plastic Manufacturing, Inc. (J&T)

and I have the following regex

```
[[:<:]](Phil-Asia Plastic Manufacturing, Inc. (J&T))
```

This doesnt work. But when I removed (J&T)) it works.

So what will be the correct regex for this?

Thanks!

Comment: In which language/engine are you having problems?

Comment: You just need to escape the round brackets and the dot. Or use `Phil-Asia Plastic Manufacturing, Inc[.] [(]J&T[)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape (or put into a character class) all special characters. When escaping [remember](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html) that:

> Because MySQL uses the *C escape syntax in strings* (for example, `\n` to represent the newline character), you must double any `\` that you use in your REGEXP strings.

It seems that you just need to escape the round brackets and the dot in your REGEXP declaration. Use

```
[[:<:]]Phil-Asia Plastic Manufacturing, Inc\\. \\(J&T\\)
```

or

```
[[:<:]]Phil-Asia Plastic Manufacturing,[[:blank:]]*Inc[.][[:blank:]]*[(]J&T[)]
```